# nodejs web site with active directory permissions

Tags: node.js, authentication, web, active-directory

Can you set up a nodejs based web site with single sign-on Windows Active Directory authentication for users?

I found [this for setting up Windows Azure AD](http://msopentech.com/blog/2013/05/22/node-js-library-for-authentication-with-windows-azure-active-directory/), but I am talking about an intranet site that would be hosted on a windows server and accessed by AD users on the intranet.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, absolutely. Checkout https://github.com/auth0/passport-windowsauth which has IIS authentication support for Windows-based LDAP profiles.